# OSX Lion I cannot access localhost from my browser

Tags: macos, apache-http-server, osx-lion, localhost, cgi

I am running mac osx 10.7.5 (My computer won't allow an upgrade). And apache 2.2.26.

I am trying to learn cgi programming with c++ (because I'm already familiar with cpp), but cannot access localhost from my browser. I have my file saved in /Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables. The file permissions are at 755.

BTW, I have written a test script in python, but it would work either.

I can ping 127.0.0.1 successfully, but when I attempt to visit http://localhost/ or http://localhost/cgi-bin/index.cgi or even new-host-192-168-1-xx.home I get the error *The requested URL / was not found on this server.*

When I run apachectl configtest I get Syntax OK. apache is running (And I've restarted it repeatedly). Web Sharing is ON.

The test file ( index.html.en ) originally worked, but my cgi program wouldn't work. I modified the index.html.en file (for kicks), and it wouldn't work, I changed it back, but still no go. Now my browser can't find anything on localhost or 127.0.0.1.

That is everything that comes to mind.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `http://localhost` (to trailing `/`). It may be a different address, depending on how server is configured.

Comment: Thanks for your response! It got the same error (404 The requested URL / was not found on this server.)